# countif string appears in another column

Tags: excel-2010, countif

I can't seem to figure out how to count all the values in 1 column only if the string also appears in another column. For example

Column A
Apple
Apple
Pear
Plum
Orange
Orange
Kiwi

Column B
Pear
Plum
Orange
Plum
Kiwi

The Countif formula of Column A should return 5 since it counts every cell in column A other than Apple since it is not in column B.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this with `COUNTIF`, but if you're able to add another column to your data, you can do the following formula.

`=IF(OR(A2=$B$2:$B$6),1,0)`

Be sure to press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the formula, as this is an array.

```
A          B          C
Apple    Pear      =IF(OR(A2=$B$2:$B$6),1,0)
Apple    Plum
Pear     Orange
Plum     Plum
Orange   Kiwi
Orange
Kiwi
```

Then you can run this formula down column C for every value in A. Finally, sum all the values in Column C to get your expected value of 5

***------EDIT--------***

If you want to do this without adding extra columns, one option is to add your own custom function (UDF). Open up the VBA editor, add a module where your UDF will reside, and then copy and paste the following code

```
Function customCount(countRange As Range, searchRange As Range)
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
For Each cell In countRange
    If Not searchRange.Find(cell) Is Nothing Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next cell
customCount = count
End Function
```

This function takes two inputs; `countRange` and `searchRange`. `countRange` is all the data in your column A, and `searchRange` is your column B (Be sure to only select the data)

If your data was just the data above, the formula you would put below your column A data would be the following

`=customCount(A2:A8,B2:B6)`

Comment: Thanks Jaycal for your suggestion. I would prefer not to have to add columns. There are multiple columns that will need to compare there values to "column B" so having the counts/totals above each column would be ideal.

Comment: ok, maybe others can help; the only other thing i can think of is to create your own custom "Countif" function (UDF) via a macro

Comment: Yes the option of a macro would be fine. Unfortunately I am not very good at creating macros like this.